# GeoServer - Caching with Response Headers Settings

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, geocaching

I'm trying to find a method to cache one layer that its data is updated every 2 hours in the DB. From what I've found the best option is using Response Cache Headers timeout http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/data/layers.html

What I've done is:

1. enable direct integration with GeoServer WMS.
2. add tiled=true parameter to WMS request
3. replace `http://GEOSERVER_URL/wms` with `http://GEOSERVER_URL/gwc/service/wms`
4. check "Response Cache Headers" with 7200 time specified as in http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/data/layers.html

and when i look at the headers I see:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=7200, must-revalidate
Content-Disposition:inline; filename=geoserver-dispatch.image
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Sun, 04 May 2014 18:38:16 GMT
Expires:Sun, 04 May 2014 20:36:36 GMT
geowebcache-cache-result:HIT
geowebcache-crs:EPSG:900913
geowebcache-gridset:EPSG:900913
geowebcache-tile-bounds:12523442.712499999,2504688.5425000004,15028131.254999999,5009377.085000001
geowebcache-tile-index:[13, 9, 4]
geowebcache-tile-index:[13, 9, 4]
Last-Modified:Sun, 04 May 2014 07:06:05 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

I thought it worked but after 2 hours the layer didn't get updated! it's like that the layer is cached and frozen like forever. I think I'm missing something. any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to specifically ask GWC to truncate whatever has been generated so far.

I have some code to do this in Python, but basically you call something like this:

```
https://URL/geoserver/gwc/rest/layers/
```

with data like this:

```
{'seedRequest':{'minX':[],'minY':[],'maxX':[],'maxY':[],'gridSetId':gs,'zoomStart':00,'zoomStop':20,'format':imf,'type':'truncate','threadCount':2}}
```

(I do some other code to identify the gridsets and image formats, gs and imf, and then truncate all of them after I write data overnight.)

If you want the full code, take a look here: https://gist.github.com/alexgleith/844146bb24b4f22d856e

Comment: Thank you! I get it now. I'm thinking of scheduling truncate request every 15 min (since I'll set the headers timeout to 15 min) do you think it's gonna work? or it be expensive for the disk or something?

Comment: Well, it removes the cache, so  you wont have cached maps. It would be better to truncate the cached images only after the data changes. Otherwise, don't use GWC and read straight from GeoServer.

Comment: okay it works now. turn out i mixed up the two methods! Thanks again.